# Installing playwright using npm gives error `command failed`

Tags: node.js, npm, web-scraping, playwright, npx

I tried to install playwright using the command

```
npm i playwright
```

But got an error

```
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path C:\Users\hpoddar\node_modules\playwright
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c node install.js

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\hpoddar\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2022-07-22T08_07_17_487Z-debug-0.log
```

`2022-07-22T08_07_17_487Z-debug-0.log` says

```
0 verbose cli [
0 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
0 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
0 verbose cli   'i',
0 verbose cli   'playwright'
0 verbose cli ]
1 info using npm@8.5.0
2 info using node@v16.14.2
3 timing npm:load:whichnode Completed in 0ms
4 timing config:load:defaults Completed in 1ms
5 timing config:load:file:C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\npmrc Completed in 2ms
6 timing config:load:builtin Completed in 3ms
7 timing config:load:cli Completed in 1ms
8 timing config:load:env Completed in 0ms
9 timing config:load:project Completed in 2ms
10 timing config:load:file:C:\Users\hpoddar\.npmrc Completed in 0ms
11 timing config:load:user Completed in 0ms
12 timing config:load:file:C:\Users\hpoddar\AppData\Roaming\npm\etc\npmrc Completed in 0ms
13 timing config:load:global Completed in 0ms
14 timing config:load:validate Completed in 0ms
15 timing config:load:credentials Completed in 0ms
16 timing config:load:setEnvs Completed in 1ms
17 timing config:load Completed in 9ms
18 timing npm:load:configload Completed in 9ms
19 timing npm:load:setTitle Completed in 0ms
20 timing config:load:flatten Completed in 1ms
21 timing npm:load:display Completed in 3ms
22 verbose logfile C:\Users\hpoddar\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2022-07-22T08_07_17_487Z-debug-0.log
23 timing npm:load:logFile Completed in 5ms
24 timing npm:load:timers Completed in 0ms
25 timing npm:load:configScope Completed in 0ms
26 timing npm:load Completed in 17ms
27 timing arborist:ctor Completed in 1ms
28 silly logfile start cleaning logs, removing 4 files
29 timing arborist:ctor Completed in 0ms
30 timing idealTree:init Completed in 6ms
31 timing idealTree:userRequests Completed in 2ms
32 silly idealTree buildDeps
33 silly fetch manifest playwright@*
34 http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/playwright 24ms (cache hit)
35 silly placeDep ROOT playwright@1.24.0 OK for:  want: *
36 silly fetch manifest playwright-core@1.24.0
37 http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/playwright-core 20ms (cache hit)
38 timing idealTree:#root Completed in 87ms
39 silly placeDep ROOT playwright-core@1.24.0 OK for: playwright@1.24.0 want: 1.24.0
40 timing idealTree:node_modules/playwright Completed in 2ms
41 timing idealTree:node_modules/playwright-core Completed in 0ms
42 timing idealTree:buildDeps Completed in 89ms
43 timing idealTree:fixDepFlags Completed in 1ms
44 timing idealTree Completed in 99ms
45 timing reify:loadTrees Completed in 99ms
46 timing reify:diffTrees Completed in 1ms
47 silly reify moves {}
48 timing reify:retireShallow Completed in 0ms
49 timing reify:createSparse Completed in 7ms
50 timing reify:loadBundles Completed in 0ms
51 silly audit bulk request { playwright: [ '1.24.0' ], 'playwright-core': [ '1.24.0' ] }
52 timing reifyNode:node_modules/playwright Completed in 58ms
53 timing reifyNode:node_modules/playwright-core Completed in 454ms
54 timing reify:unpack Completed in 454ms
55 timing reify:unretire Completed in 0ms
56 timing build:queue Completed in 1ms
57 timing build:link:node_modules/playwright-core Completed in 0ms
58 timing build:link:node_modules/playwright Completed in 6ms
59 timing build:link Completed in 6ms
60 info run playwright@1.24.0 install node_modules/playwright node install.js
61 http fetch POST 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/-/npm/v1/security/advisories/bulk 606ms
62 timing auditReport:getReport Completed in 607ms
63 silly audit report {}
64 timing auditReport:init Completed in 0ms
65 timing reify:audit Completed in 608ms
66 info run playwright@1.24.0 install { code: 1, signal: null }
67 timing reify:rollback:createSparse Completed in 618ms
68 timing reify:rollback:retireShallow Completed in 0ms
69 timing command:i Completed in 8869ms
70 verbose stack Error: command failed
70 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\@npmcli\promise-spawn\index.js:64:27)
70 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:526:28)
70 verbose stack     at maybeClose (node:internal/child_process:1092:16)
70 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:302:5)
71 verbose pkgid playwright@1.24.0
72 verbose cwd C:\Users\hpoddar
73 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.22000
74 verbose argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "i" "playwright"
75 verbose node v16.14.2
76 verbose npm  v8.5.0
77 error code 1
78 error path C:\Users\hpoddar\node_modules\playwright
79 error command failed
80 error command C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c node install.js
81 verbose exit 1
82 timing npm Completed in 9246ms
83 verbose unfinished npm timer reify 1658477237859
84 verbose unfinished npm timer reify:build 1658477238429
85 verbose unfinished npm timer build 1658477238429
86 verbose unfinished npm timer build:deps 1658477238429
87 verbose unfinished npm timer build:run:install 1658477238436
88 verbose unfinished npm timer build:run:install:node_modules/playwright 1658477238436
89 verbose code 1
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can delete the `node_modules` folder and the `package-lock.json` file and try running the command again.

There are two other ways you can install Playwright.

1. Using the interactive way as mentioned in the [playwright docs](https://playwright.dev/docs/intro)

```js
npm init playwright@latest
```

2. Using the sequence of commands ([Reference](https://github.com/Microsoft/playwright#manually)):

```js
npm i -D @playwright/test

# install supported browsers
npx playwright install
```

Comment: did not work, same error

Comment: I have updated the answer to installing the playwright in two other ways. Maybe you can try those?

Comment: I did not try your updated answer, I was getting error while installing even after I deleted the node modules folder. But just now I tried again by giving the command npm i playwright and it worked! don't know why :p

Comment: I don't know if I should accept or not, but if someone face this problem in future and says that this answer did not work for them I ll retract the `accept`

Comment: Cleaning npm cache worked for me

'npm cache clean --force'

Answer (score 3):

It seems there is an issue because it will fail to override \npm\playwright , the following script did it for me, as it forces to override it with --force.

```html
npm init playwright@latest --force
```